# Is there any way in python while iterating through a collection to get the current counter numeric value?

Tags: python

I know that I can set up an integer before the loop and increment it together with the loop. But is there another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just [`enumerate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate) the iterable:

```
for index, obj in enumerate(objects):
    print index
```

(The name `object` is a built-in type.  To avoid shadowing this name, I renamed the loop variable to `obj`.)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)

```
for counter, obj in emumerate(objects):
    print counter
```